# How to hard code values here in Mybatis if I have to add company item?

Tags: mybatis

```
<foreach item="companySizeItem" index="companySizeIndex" collection="CompanySize">
    <choose>
        <when test="companySizeItem >0 "> and b."companyId"=cp."companyId"  
            and b."companyId" IN
            <foreach item="companyitem" index="companyindex"
                collection="Companies" open="(" separator="," close=")">
                ${companyitem}
            </foreach>
        </when>
    </choose>
</foreach>
```

I want to add some hard coded values for company item. Where should I add them?

Comment: What sql do you want to write?

Comment: i want to eliminate this mybatis thing out of this whole code and just write in sql query for some hard code values .. can you please say me how to

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I did not mistake your question, for hard code, it should be following:

```
and b."companyId"=cp."companyId"  
and b."companyId" IN ('companyId1', 'companyId1')
```

and only if there are company ids, these two criteria should be added into your sql.

Comment: Thanks much buddy.